# Multiple table joins - delete query - optimum way

Tags: mysql

This is a query which takes 1 to 2 secs to execute (mysql query)

```
DELETE t1 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3, table4 t4 
WHERE (t1.column1 = t2.column1 OR t1.colum2 = t2.column1) 
AND t2.column1 = t3.column1 
AND t3.column2 = t4.column1
AND t4.column2=100;
```

I am looking the execution time in few millisecs. Is there any optimum way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes to the tables, this will improve delete performance as well as queries.

Comment: Indexes are already added, may be the way am joining should be re-looked.

Comment: Also indexes play vital role in select queries, more indexes will slow down any update/delete queries.

Comment: If the indexes significantly reduce the number of records that the that have to be considered then it will drastically improve even deletes. Try doing EXPLAIN on an equivalent query that selects the results you want to delete, then maybe you could optimize the indexes. Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM, if it is querying the results quickly but taking a long time to delete then it switching to MyISAM will improve the deletes, but has other drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it into two distinct delete queries and removing the "OR" clause.  An OR clause like that will often cause full table scans.  If necessary, use a transaction to ensure both queries execute since they are broken into two pieces.

Answer (score 0):

The way to optimise it is by adding indexes - but it's hard to tell from your query where the indexes would be useful. Try using a standard JOIN syntax; that will help you work out the difference between the ON clause and the WHERE clause, and where different indexes might help.